# Method to call a field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any method for when been called an object it returns a field of that object?

```
function Int16(v) { this.v=v }; var n = new Int16(10);

// Instead of "n.v", I would want to use "n" directly
if (n.v == 10) { console.log("ok") }
```

Comment: Seeing that you posted quite a few questions regarding this topic in the last days, I'd like to add the following: There is simply no way to overload operators in JS (without reducing the values to primitive types). If you really want to persue the path you're going, use self defined object methods (e.g. `eqals`, `add`, `compare`, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var n = new Int16(10);` *will* set `n` to a reference to an object of your `Int16` type.

What you're looking for may be to set the `valueOf` and `toString` functions to return the value of `v`.

Comment: I had set the `valueOf` method but it does not works in comparisons.

Comment: @Marc: no, comparing two different `Int16` objects will not yield equality simply because the value of their `v` are equal. `==` does not compare only primitives. You could implement your own `equals`, but you'd have similar problems for greater than, etc.

Comment: @DavidHedlund yet comparing `Int16` to `Number` should cast to string, am I correct?

Comment: @JanDvorak: yes, `n == 10` would work, but `n == n2` (where `n2 = Int16(10)`) wouldn't.

Comment: @DavidHedlund, in change does not works `n !== 10`, `if (n !== 10) { console.log("fail") }` since it shows *fail*.

Comment: @Marc: `!==` (and `===`) is "(in)equality *without type coersion*". You're explicitly telling javascript not to consider the two values equal if they are of different types, and they are. `n != 10` yields `false`, `n !== 10` yields `true`.